# Will converting my C++20 project to use Modules be easier if implemented as header files only or separate header/source files?

Tags: c++, module, c++20

I have not found a compelling reason to implement my personal projects as separate header/source files. Fewer files to work with and IDE support make it a complete non-issue for navigating and editing. If necessary, a detail namespace is used.

But will there be an advantage to converting a project to use C++ modules if it is separated into separate header and source files?

It comes up at work once in a while, I'm asking for more opinions.

Comment: I haven't used C++20 modules yet, but I think they'll make a big difference for large projects.  A small difference for medium sized projects (less than, oh, say, 1000 source files).  And no practical difference for small projects (under 100 source files).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From one perspective, the main point of modules as a concept is to make the way you're coding things *efficient* to compile. That is, the whole idea with modules is that you *don't* need "header files" and "source files" per-se.

As it currently stands, including one of your headers requires compiling everything in that file, as well as everything in every file it includes, recursively. This is *why* we don't shove all our code into header files. For any serious project, this will negatively impact compile times.

Modules makes it so that this style of coding can compile quite fast. So it's quite the opposite: modules will *encourage* you to code in your current style, not oppose it.

Answer (score 0):

Modules can be split into *module interface units* and *module implementation units*.

For small projects, it is often convenient to dump everything into the primary interface unit, and not worry about potential inefficiencies. Be aware, however, that when you update an interface unit, any translation unit that imports it is a candidate for recompilation. This is true even when the updates did not impact the exported names from the module.

When you put code into an implementation file, then the interface is not affected by changes to the implementation. None of the translation units that import a module will be recompiled when the implementation changes, just the implementation unit itself.

The same thing applies to *module partition interface units* and *module partition implementation units*. Code in the implementation unit can be changed without triggering a chain of recompilations.